# Grafana : Compare with same day of the week last year

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have dashboard with a single stat panel showing the number of bookings for the current day. I need to show the same information (in order to compare) for the same of the week for last year on the same dashboard.

I know there is the "Time shift" feature in the panel but I don't want to set 364 days because I will not be sure to compare the same day.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Reagards,

Comment: Pls provide more details about used datasource and query.

Comment: I use elasticsearch database. The query is very simple, it’s just a simple count.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using InfluxDB/Flux you could `timeShift` your data independently from the Grafana UI.